# Can I bind multiple values as a single parameter using MYSQLI and PHP?

Tags: php, sql, mysql, mysqli

Imagine I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT id,name FROM user WHERE id IN ('id1','id2','id3')
```

Now imagine I need the array of ids to be supplied by PHP.  So I have something like this:

```
$idList = array('id1','id2','id3');
$query = "SELECT id,name FROM user WHERE id IN (?)";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param(/*Something*/);
```

What can I replace `/*Something*/` with to get the same results as the original query?  Or do I need to put in 3 question marks in the query format?  The only reason I don't want to do that is because the number of question marks is variable, so I would have to build the query string manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I bind multiple values as a single
>   parameter using MYSQLI and PHP?

No you cannot.

For your situation, you should build the query string programmatically. If you are guaranteed it will always be three values, you could add three markers to the SQL then bind via looping over the array.

Comment: Which means I suppose that I will have to use call_user_func_array to actually call the bind_param method as well

Comment: You could just loop through the array.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that?  How?  I've only ever bound parameters all at once.

Answer (score 5):

You can use PHP to write out the placeholders `?` using `str_repeat()`, and then just `bind_param` all your params in a loop.

Just be careful of the trailing comma that str_repeat will return. Either `rtrim()` it or instead use `array_fill()` to create an array of repeating placeholders and then `join()` those to create your placeholders string.

```
$arrPlaceholders = array_fill(0, count($idList), '?') ;
$strPlaceholders = join(', ', $arrPlaceholders) ;
```

Then your query can be:

```
$query = "SELECT id,name FROM user WHERE id IN ($strPlaceholders)";
```

And you can bind your parameters in a loop.

Comment: Can I use a loop to bind parameters with MYSQLI?  How?  When looking at mysqli_stmt_bind_param I see this: "The number of variables and length of string types must match the parameters in the statement."

Comment: @Ed that's actually an interesting issue I hadn't noticed straight away, as I don't use mysqli. It does look like `bind_param()` needs to include all the parameters in that one call, so a loop will not work. Looking at the manual, some people have thought of some smart solutions to it: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php#89097 and the one below it that suggests `call_user_func_array()`

Answer (score 1):

This might be a bit old, but I was wondering this myself. So I performed a benchmark. First, I created a simple table:

```
SELECT * from random LIMIT 10;
+----+------------+
| id | rand_stuff |
+----+------------+
|  1 | 1988585319 | 
|  2 | 1926594853 | 
|  3 |  820681972 | 
|  4 |  950331574 | 
|  5 |  540721998 | 
|  6 | 1284256353 | 
|  7 |   12804417 | 
|  8 | 2130482967 | 
|  9 | 2018786156 | 
| 10 |  285818156 | 
+----+------------+

SELECT count(id) from random;
+-----------+
| count(id) |
+-----------+
|   3365586 | 
+-----------+

/var/lib/mysql/benchmark# ls -laFh
total 101M
drwx------ 2 mysql mysql 4.0K 2011-05-28 00:06 ./
drwxr-xr-x 7 mysql mysql 4.0K 2011-05-27 23:53 ../
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql   65 2011-05-27 23:53 db.opt
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 8.4K 2011-05-28 00:06 random.frm
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql  55M 2011-05-28 00:32 random.MYD
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql  47M 2011-05-28 00:32 random.MYI
```

Its a trivial structure that weighs in at ~100 MB. The random number was created with php's mt_rand() function.

Here's "Fetch.php":

```
<?php

$loops = $argv[1];

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "bench", "bench", "benchmark");
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    printf("Connect Failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT rand_stuff FROM random WHERE id = ?")){
    for($i=1; $i<$loops; $i++){
        $stmt->bind_param("i", $i) or die;
        $stmt->execute() or die;
        $stmt->bind_result($value) or die;
        $stmt->fetch();      
        echo "$i \t $value\n";
    }
    $stmt->close();
}
```

And some benchmarks:

```
$time php fetch.php 10 > /dev/null

real    0m0.043s
user    0m0.024s
sys 0m0.012s

$ time php fetch.php 100 > /dev/null

real    0m0.057s
user    0m0.044s
sys 0m0.000s

$ time php fetch.php 1000 > /dev/null

real    0m0.166s
user    0m0.080s
sys 0m0.012s

$ time php fetch.php 10000 > /dev/null

real    0m1.083s
user    0m0.412s
sys 0m0.124s
```

Here's fetch2.php

```
<?php

$loops = $argv[1];

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "bench", "bench", "benchmark");
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    printf("Connect Failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$array = array();

for($i=1; $i<$loops; $i++){
    $array[] = $i;
}

$joined_array = join($array, ',');

$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT id, rand_stuff FROM random WHERE id IN ($joined_array)");

while($row = $results->fetch_row()){
    $val1 = $row[0];
    $val2 = $row[1];
    echo "$val1\t$val2\n";
}
```

And here are its related benchmarks.

```
$time php fetch2.php 10 > /dev/null

real    0m0.037s
user    0m0.028s
sys 0m0.008s

$time php fetch2.php 100 > /dev/null

real    0m0.044s
user    0m0.032s
sys 0m0.008s

$ time php fetch2.php 1000 > /dev/null

real    0m0.050s
user    0m0.036s
sys 0m0.016s


$ time php fetch2.php 10000 > /dev/null
real    0m0.117s
user    0m0.088s
sys 0m0.024s
```

Side By Side, we get this table (Fetch.php is "WHERE id = ?" and prepared statements, while Fetch2.php uses the " WHERE x IN ()" syntax on a dumb query):

```
+--------+-----------+------------+
|  Loop  | Fetch.php | Fetch2.php |
+--------+-----------+------------+
| 10     |  .043s    |  .037s     |
| 100    |  .057s    |  .044s     |
| 1000   |  .116s    |  .050s     |
| 10000  | 1.083s    |  .117s     |
+--------+-----------+------------+
```

Clearly, "Fetch2.php" is more efficient, but in this benchmark... it doesn't seem to really matter until you get into the 100+ elements range. Iterating over the prepared statement is simple and secure (no chance of SQL Injection at all), and doesn't seem to be much slower at the ~10 elements range. Repeating the test with ~10 elements can sometimes have "Fetch.php" win the benchmark. Overall, Fetch2.php won of course, but they're definitely close at this range.

I'd be inclined to say that... if you have less than 100 elements, just take advantage of the prepared statement and execute it repeatedly. That's what prepared statements are designed for after all. Nothing beats a single-round trip to the database of course, but the prepared statement approach may have acceptable performance. Of course, benchmark on your own system. Most likely, the above test was too trivial (there aren't any joins or subqueries... and the db is on the same system as the php script...)