# php mysqli binding issue with IN clause

Tags: php, mysqli

```
$artist_user_ids = implode(',',$artist_user_ids);
$referrer = "referrer IN (?)";
$query = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE $referrer";
$con = db_connect();
$stmt = db_prepare($con, $query);
bind_param('s', $artist_user_ids);
```

That does not work.  But if I change the 1st line to:

```
$artist_user_ids = "'" . implode(',',$artist_user_ids) . "'";
```

It works like a charm.  What gives?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I bind multiple values as a single parameter using MYSQLI and PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753295/can-i-bind-multiple-values-as-a-single-parameter-using-mysqli-and-php)

Comment: @Michael Not quite.  My question is: **why**?  `implode()` returns a string.  Why do I need to quote a string?

Comment: Because the IN clause takes multiple parameters. To bind them, they need to be bound as multiple parameters. A string of values cannot be evaluated into multiple parameters  - doing so would break the security benefits parameterized queries provide.

Comment: @Michael I see.  But then why does it work when I embrace it with single quotes?

Comment: Because then you're passing it as one single value to `IN()` so instead of doing a query against all the comma-separated values, you're querying for the single string of comma-separated values. The values are not exploded out from the string, and you'll likely get no results back.

Comment: @Michael  That makes a lot of sense.  What does not make sense is that I _did_ get the correct results with the single unexploded string.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @Michael My apologies.  On further investigation, the returned results are different.  Thank you.

Comment: Ok, I was feeling pretty confused and almost started setting up a test scenario to see for myself...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id FROM users WHERE referrer IN ('val1, val2, ...');
```

but its not quite correct .... You have to do it other way